# Fractional motion and SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]

Tags: probability-or-statistics, warning-messages, debugging

```
proc = FractionalBrownianMotionProcess[0, 0.1, 0.15];
SeedRandom["mathematica.SE/58539"];
dat = RandomFunction[proc, {0, 10 , 1}][[2]][[1]][[1]];
FindProcessParameters[dat, FractionalBrownianMotionProcess[m, s, hu]]
```

produce in most of the cases the problem

> SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]

Any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: Works for me, outputting {m -> -0.0146255, s -> 0.0826785, hu -> 8.88824*10^-134}.

Comment: I get the same as @user64494. What version of Mathematica and platform are you using?

Comment: Works fine when I drop or even only change the `SeedRandom`. Indeed, as it stands it produces an error. Seems like that particular seed leads to a path that `FindProcessParameters` can't handle with such a short path. Simply changing the length from 11 points to at least 16 gets rid of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Versión of mathematica 11.2 I have solved it increasing the  number of data,  superior to 15 no problem, less tan 15 error mesages. Thanks